# TypeError: Cannot read property 'push' of undefined Mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am getting the below error which doing a app in Node.js using express.
I am using Mongoose for my DB operations below i have detailed my design

Party.js

```
var mongoose = require("mongoose");

var partySchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    partyName: String,
    songs: [
         {
                 type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
                ref: "Song"
         }
   ]
});

module.exports = mongoose.model("Party", partySchema);
```

Song.js

```
var mongoose = require("mongoose");

var songsSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    videoId: String,
    videoName: String
});

module.exports = mongoose.model("Song", songsSchema);
```

My App.js

```
app.post("/search/addSong", function(req, res) {
    Party.find({partyName:"hello"},function(err,party){
        if(err){
            console.log("Failed in find");
        } else {
            console.log(party);
            // console.log(typeof(req.body.videoId));
            var videoId = req.body.videoId;

            var newSong = [ {
                videoId:req.body.videoId,
                videoName:req.body.videoName
            }
            ];
            Song.create(newSong, function(err, createdSong){
       if(err){
           console.log("Error creating a new party");
       } else  {
           console.log(createdSong);
           party.songs.push(createdSong);// ERROR ON THIS LINE
           party.save();
           res.redirect("/search");
       }
    });
        }
    });
    res.render("addSong");
});
```

I am able to create collection objects of the Party and Song individually, when I add the song to the party queue, I get the following error:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'push' of undefined
```

Can anyone please let me know what I a missing in here..!!

Thanks in advance.!!

Answer (score 0):

find returns a cursor which is converted in an array. if you are expecting a single doc, call findOne.

```
app.post("/search/addSong", function(req, res) {
    Party.findOne({partyName:"hello"},function(err,party){
        if(err){
            console.log("Failed in find");
        } else {
            console.log(party);
            // console.log(typeof(req.body.videoId));
            var videoId = req.body.videoId;

            var newSong = [ {
                videoId:req.body.videoId,
                videoName:req.body.videoName
            }
            ];
            Song.create(newSong, function(err, createdSong){
       if(err){
           console.log("Error creating a new party");
       } else  {
           console.log(createdSong);
           party.songs.push(createdSong);// ERROR ON THIS LINE
           party.save(function(err){
             res.redirect("/search");
           });
       }
    });
        }
    });
    res.render("addSong");
});
```

Also put redirect in the callback of save, it will make sure that redirect is called only when save is completed, otherwise it would redirect without saving, giving the asynchronous nature of javascript.

Comment: The problem is with the line where I am trying to push the object into the another object.

Comment: The problem still is there when you use findOne as suggested in answer?